# Vote for some party/person or Vote party/person?

Tags: verbs

Do we **vote for** some party/person or just **vote them**?

> *Vote for XYZ.* **Vs** *Vote XYZ.*

**Note:** *vote* should be considered as a *verb* only. I'm clear about it as a *noun.*

Answer (score 2):

You vote **for** or **against** s.o.

> I voted for/against the democrats.
>   I voted for/against so and so.

But vote can also be **transitive** :

> I voted Democrat because....

→ here it's the idea/the movement rather than the people.

Comment: *I voted for Democrat because...* is correct?

Comment: Is _I voted for Democrat because_... correct? No, but _I voted for Democrats because..._ would be correct, as would _I voted for Democrat candidates because..._

Comment: note: "the Democrat party" or "the Democrat candidate" is a pejorative used by Republicans. You should say "the Democratic party" if you want to appear politically neutral. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democrat_Party_%28epithet%29

Comment: "MPs voted the bill." would not be correct in British English; you need "for" or "against", or "on".

Comment: To nitpick further, even with "for" present, that sentence would still not mean the same as "MPs passed the bill", as while MPs can vote on bills, it's not them who (technically speaking) pass bills, it's the House.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Actually you're right it's vote a bill down/up. I'll rectify. Thanks.